# AutoReconnect: No replica set members available for query with ReadPreference PRIMARY_PREFERRED

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

**Question** What's the best way to handle this kind of error? Retries after say, 30 seconds for a max. of 5 times?

**Setup**
I have a PRIMARY + two SECONDARY setup on AWS ECS and none of the boxes have been down.

From the exception message, it seems like Mongo is saying "I don't have PRIMARY and I tried to get you data from SECONDARY but they're down too".  But, none of the Mongo servers were down. I had another process running which has a default `read_preference` of `SECONDARY` and that has been running fine.

**Exception**

```
is_auth = db.authenticate("myid","mypass")
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line
720, in authenticate
   read_preference=read_pref)["nonce"]
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/database.py", line
390, in command
   result = self["$cmd"].find_one(command, **extra_opts)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/collection.py",
line 598, in find_one
   for result in self.find(spec_or_id, *args, **kwargs).limit(-1):
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line
814, in next
   if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line
763, in _refresh
   self.__uuid_subtype))
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line
700, in __send_message
   **kwargs)
 File 
"/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo/mongo_replica_set_client.py
", line 1210, in _send_message_with_response
   raise AutoReconnect(msg, errors)


AutoReconnect: No replica set members available for query with
ReadPreference PRIMARY_PREFERRED
```

**Code**

```
connection = MongoReplicaSetClient(, replicaSet='myReplica-2', use_greenlets = True) 
db = "my_real_db"
db.read_preference = ReadPreference.PRIMARY
is_auth = db.authenticate("myid", "mypass") # ERROR at this line
```

**Versions**
MongoDB: 2.2.0 and PyMongo: 2.4.2

Comment: You're right about the meaning of the message. `MongoReplicaSetClient` actually uses `PRIMARY_PREFERRED` mode for `authenticate()` no matter what read preference you've configured on it, so the configuration shouldn't matter.

I see you set `use_greenlets`--are you also calling `gevent.monkey.patch_socket()`?

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis Thanks for the note. Yes, I am calling gevent.monkey.patch_socket() before the code above gets invoked.

Comment: It may have just been a network hiccup, not unheard of in EC2, between your Python program and the replica set that coincided with the call to authenticate(). But before I attempt to answer your question I want to make sure there's no bug. Can you replicate this behavior?

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis This issue happens atleast once a day...although I am not aware what causes it. It could just be an EC2 hiccup as you pointed out on that machine but there's no definite way of knowing.

Comment: Is it always in authenticate()? Is your app calling authenticate() frequently? Do other functions besides authenticate() raise AutoReconnect as well? Besides the read_preference what else is different between the app that shows the problem and the app that doesn't?

Comment: @A.JesseJiryuDavis It's always in authenticate() at the same line. So far, the stacktrace always shows error at that line ...and the same message - no PRIMARY_PREFERRED replicasets available. The only difference is the read_preference. The app that works fine has a default SECONDARY read_preference.

Comment: @SagarHatekar What was your connectTimeoutMS value?

Comment: @Tuanitim I wish I remembered it buddy but should be somewhere in the range of 2000-5000 ms, I am pretty sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check your `connectTimeoutMS` and `socketTimeoutMS`. May be, it's very small?

Comment: if query need a long time, should set connectTimeoutMS and socketTimeoutMS for a long time.

Answer (score 8):

I would double check your replica set configuration. Run `rs.status()` on one of your replica set members and make sure that the 'name' field for each member is in fact correct and resolves from the machine your application is running on.

Answer (score 2):

I also had problems with this issue.

1. Run `rs.status()`and note the machine name of the "syncingTo" field.
2. Edit `/etc/hosts` by adding that machine name with IP.
3. Rerun script.

Mongo documentation on configuring `/etc/hosts` found [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/).